# Can Schwinger effect occur in electric field of a nucleus?

Tags: electric-fields, pair-production

I know that electron-positron pairs can be produced within a uniform electric field with electric field strength above $10^{18}V$. Electric field of such strength can be found near atomic nuclei. So if one has an atomic nucleus free of its electrons, can electron-positron pairs be produced at it's surface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a naked (no electrons near it) charged nucleus with $Z= 137 $ then the Dirac equation predicts that  the binding energy for a single electron becomes equal to $-m_{\rm e}c^2$. Beyond that value of $Z$  the Dirac equation has no real-energy solution. The usual accounts take this to mean that  an electron-positron pair will be produced, the positron escapes to infinity and the electron falls into the nucleus where it  converts a proton to a neutron so    $Z$ is reduced by one. The process continues until $Z<137$ and the vacuum becomes stable again. See [here](http://jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/dn/e_032_03_0526.pdf)

So the answer to your question is "yes" in theory, but no nuclei with $Z>137$ are available for experimental study.

Added material: I am amending my answer  slighltly after further reading.  That no solutions exist  to the Dirac equation with a point charge $Z>137$ is due to the singular character of the Coulomb potential of the  point-charge Dirac equation. This is a mathematical pathology  of the point-charge idealization, and not a physical instability. At that point  the lowest energy state has $E=0$ ( i.e $-m_{\rm e}c^2$ below the lowest energy of a free electron). An electron can appear and   occupy the zero-energy state with no energy cost -- but that electron has to come from somewhere and the resulting positron costs energy $+m_{\rm e}c^2$ --- so that the vacuum  is not yet unstable to pair creation.

If one has an extended charge distribtion due to a finite size nucleus the "falling into the center" pathology of   the Dirac equation is obviated, and the bound state energies can get below $E=0$ and reach $E=-m_{\rm e}c^2$. This is the top of the negative-energy spectrum for the free electron and so *now* one can produce electron-positron pairs at no cost. The electron will bind in the lowest energy state of the Dirac equation and the positron will escape to infinity.

Comment: Actually, Schwartz does the converse of this. In chapter 33 while explaining Schwinger effect he states how the phenomenon is invoked to explain why the periodic table has less than 137 elements.